# time lapse graphs matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a matplotlib graph that shows how to a certain data set changes over time. What I've been trying to do is create a plot and show it, pause for one second, clear the plot, and then show the next one in the array. I've gotten pretty close with the code below, but sadly it just crashes as is.

```
for expo in sorted_data:
    plt.plot(expo["x"], expo["y"])
    plt.show(block=False)
    time.sleep(1)
    plt.gcf().clear()
```

sorted_data contains the data sorted by when the data was collected.

Answer (score 1):

Use `matplotlib.animation`. You can find many examples here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/index.html